# How to use RegExp in javascript?

Tags: javascript

i am newbie to regex in javascript and i got stuck in using regex in javascript.

I have two scenerio

1) I have a string like `aaa/+/bbb/+` , i want to match this string with strings `aaa/1/bbb/hello123` and `aaa/1/bbb/` using regex and both should return `true`. If i pass aaa/1/bbb then it should give `false`

2) If i have string aaa/# then it should match all the above strings and returmn true

Can any one help me?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the significance of `+` and `#` is? It looks like `+` is intended to match one or more numbers and letters, but it's not clear.

Comment: `2) If i have string aaa/# then it should match all the above strings and returmn true` - no it shouldn't

Comment: @JaromandaX Can you explain? They are simply defining custom wildcard characters. I don't see how `#` shouldn't be aloud to have that meaning.

Comment: @4castle - one does not make ones own rules for how RegExp works ... `aaa/#` will not match the strings given. But I think I understand where I went wrong, I assumed he meant that `aaa/#` was actually a RegExp - re-reading the question, I see he wants someone to write some code for his own pattern matching scheme, possibly using RegExp as required - this is not icanhazcode.com so I wish him the best of luck in his quest to get free programming done

Comment: `i got stuck in using regex` - you sure have, @Qasim, you haven't got ANY code at all - good luck

Comment: + means only upto one level and # means there may be multiple levels followed by slashes

Answer (score 1):

In regex, the `+` would translate to `[^/]*`, and the `#` would translate to `.*`.

The next step is to escape special characters in the input string. [This regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/5743988) has that purpose. Since the `+` is a special character, we will have to unescape manually.

```js
RegExp.escape= function(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
};

function matchesPattern(pattern, input) {
  pattern = RegExp.escape(pattern);            // escape special characters
  pattern = pattern.replace(/\\\+/g, "[^/]*"); // replace '\+'
  pattern = pattern.replace(/#/g, ".*");     // replace '#'
  pattern = new RegExp("^" + pattern + "$");   // construct regex
  return pattern.test(input);                  // test input
}

console.log(matchesPattern("aaa/+/bbb/+", "aaa/1/bbb/hello123"));
console.log(matchesPattern("aaa/+/bbb/+", "aaa/1/bbb/"));
console.log(matchesPattern("aaa/+/bbb/+", "aaa/1/bbb"));

console.log(matchesPattern("aaa/#", "aaa/1/bbb/hello123"));
console.log(matchesPattern("aaa/#", "aaa/1/bbb/"));
console.log(matchesPattern("aaa/#", "aaa/1/bbb"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression `^aaa\/[0-9]+\/bbb\/[\w\d]*$` will match the following strings:

```
aaa/1/bbb/hello123
aaa/1/bbb/
```

These strings will not be matched:

```
aaa/1/bbb
```

I am unclear about your second scenario - are you saying that the regex should also match the string `aaa/#`?

You can use regex in javascript like so:

```
var re = /^aaa\/[0-9]+\/bbb\/[\w\d]*$/;
var matches = re.test("aaa/1/bbb/");
if (matches) { console.log("it matches!"); }
```

Comment: Use `re.test(str)` in order to see if there is a match.

Comment: Thanks 4castle - forgot about that method, will update.